# Is it possible to skip the first line in a theorem environment?

Tags: line-breaking, theorems

I'm currently writing up some solutions, and I like to rewrite the problem before answering it.

I've set exercise to be a theorem environment, and the code I'm using is

```
\begin{exercise} 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item Show that $R$ is symmetric iff $R^{-1}\subseteq R$.
\item Show that $R$ is transitive iff $R\circ R\subseteq R$.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\end{exercise}
```

However, when I build, the first item (a) appears immediately to the right of the Exercise heading, and the second item (b) appears below and indented:

[image]

I've tried using `\newline` and `\linebreak`, and even skipping a line before typing `\begin{enumerate}` after the `\begin{exercise}` command but those don't work. Is there a way to push (a) down below Exercise 3.32. so that it's lined up with (b)? Thank you.

As requested, my preamble is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input{other/packages.tex}
\input{other/theoremdef.tex}
```

where packages.tex is

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[top=1.3in, bottom=1.3in, left=1.3in, right=1.3in]{geometry}

% header and footer
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xy}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
```

And theoremdef.tex is:

```
\newtheorem{exercise}{\bf Exercise}
\newcommand{\dom}{\text{dom}\ }
\newcommand{\ran}{\text{ran}\ }
\newcommand{\fld}{\text{fld}\ }
\newcommand{\op}[2]{\langle #1,#2\rangle}
\newcommand{\ot}[3]{\langle #1,#2,#3\rangle}
\newcommand{\ms}[1]{\mathscr{#1}}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Insert

```
\leavevmode
```

after the `\begin{exercise}`.  That puts you into horizontal mode, which is where you want to be when you encounter the `\begin{enumerate}`.

Comment: Thanks Phil, this worked great. This may be a dumb question, but will I ever have to "return to vmode", as in undo the \leavevmode command, or does it leave later parts of the document unaffected?

Comment: @yunone: `\leavevmode` works as `\mbox{}`, it does not affect other part of document.

Comment: This adds a lot of vertical space. I added `\vspace*{-\bigskipamount}\vspace*{-\medskipamount}` which removes the space again, but I'm not 100% sure that it's the right amount of space.

Comment: @Phil Hirschhorn I think that ``\leavevmode`` does not work when for example we write ``\begin{definition}\leavevmode
cccccc
\end{definition}``. What will be the solution? thanks

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
\begin{exercise} 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item[]
\item Show that $R$ is symmetric iff $R^{-1}\subseteq R$.
\item Show that $R$ is transitive iff $R\circ R\subseteq R$.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me when the `\leavevmode` solution suggested above created compilation errors ("`Improper \prevdepth.`")).

Comment: این برایم مفید بود. متشکرم

Answer (score 8):

See `theorem` or `ntheorem` package. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{theorem} % or ntheorem
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

It may be a little more complex to do that using `amsthm`. In `amsthm` we can define:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}{3pt}{3pt}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
```

It works fine *without* a `enumerate` environment at the beginning, but will fail for your code. This is a solution:

```
\begin{exercise}\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

It seems no elegant solution. Therefore I prefer `ntheorem` to modify theorem styles.

Answer (score 4):

I've extracted the following from `thmtools`' handling of the `listhack` key:

```
\def\thmt@amsthmlistbreakhack{%
  \leavevmode
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \par
  \everypar{\setbox\z@\lastbox\everypar{}}%
}
```

I find that without the `\vspace`, the vertical space before the list is excessive. I don't remember right now why I put the `\everypar` stanza there, in particular, why I didn't use `\noindent`. I'll check that again.

Answer (score 2):

I (sort of accidentally) discovered that simply using `\item` immediately after `\begin{theorem}` can achieve the desired effect. For example, try

```
\begin{theorem}[Name of Theorem]
\item This is a theorem with multiple parts.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item stuff here.
    \item and here.
    \item and here, as well.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

I haven't yet found an instance that this fails for. Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you elaborate on your solution and show some screen shot?

Comment: This works nicer for me than \leavevmode - that is because leavevmode seems to cause a new paragraph (i.e., there is "too much" spacing between the theorem name and the enumeration). A blank \item line by itself looks much nicer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\newline` as a quick fix. As newline needs a line to break, you can give an empty one by `~`.

```
\begin{exercise} 
~\newline
\begin{enumerate} 
\item Show that $R$ is symmetric iff $R^{-1}\subseteq R$.
\item Show that $R$ is transitive iff $R\circ R\subseteq R$.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\end{exercise}
```

Answer (score -1):

As Leo Liu suggested, I do this:

```
\begin{theorem}
  \mbox{}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item foo
  \item bar
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```