# Skipping line after "Proof" in proof environment

Tags: line-breaking, theorems

Like the OP in [Is it possible to skip the first line in a theorem environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/is-it-possible-to-skip-the-first-line-in-a-theorem-environment), I would like to be able to skip a line after the word "Proof" so that the first line of the proof is actually part of its own paragraph. For whatever reason the `\leavevmode` command suggested in the answer to the referenced question doesn't always work; it only seems to work whenever the body of the proof consists of an enumeration. I'm just using the [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package with the default settings. Is there a command that can be issued at the beginning of the proof that will allow me to skip a line? Of course, like the OP, I've tried `\\` and variants thereof and am only rewarded with the obnoxious "There's no line here to end" error.

Comment: I'd say that `\begin{proof}\mbox{}\\*` should do. (I'd never go to a new line, though.) In **amsthm** the `proof` environment is *not* implemented as a theorem-like one (differently from **ntheorem**), so those advices don't necessary work for `proof`.

Comment: As suggested by the UK TeX FAQ entry on [No line here to end](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=noline), you could also use `\hspace*{\fill}`. As @egreg suggests, the implementation of [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)'s `proof` environment is that of a `trivlist`.

Comment: If you would like to do this consistently for the whole document, you could define `\newenvironment{myproof}{\proof\mbox{}\\*}{\endproof}`.

Comment: @egreg That seemed to do the trick. Would I be better off overall anyway if I transitioned to ntheorem?

Comment: I always use **amsthm**. :)

Comment: @Stefan: as implicitly pointed out by Gonzalo, `proof` has an optional argument.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: Thanks, I included support for it and made an answer from this then.

Comment: Simply put ~ after \begin{proof}

Comment: @D063520 Thank you, `\begin{proof}~` is the easiest and quickest solution 

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If this is to apply to all the `proof` environments in your document, you can redefine the `proof` environment to add `\\*` after the proof name has been written; here's such a redefinition (a `\mbox{}` will be necessary before `\\*`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\mbox{}\\*
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Use \hfill:

```
\begin{lemma}
balbla
\begin{proof}
\hfill
\begin{enumerate}
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{lemma}
```

Comment: I like this solution, since I am needing it only in few cases, not in every `proof` environment. Thanks for that.

Comment: Very simple! :)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of redefining the `proof` environment, you could define your own, based on `proof` but leaving the old `proof` intact, and you need just one line:

```
\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{\proof[#1]\mbox{}\\*}{\endproof}
```

Using a new name makes also clear, that it's a different proof environment. Further, you are still able to use the original `proof` in cases when you don't like a line break, for example if the proof would consist of one short equation or a reference.

**Complete example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{\proof[#1]\mbox{}\\*}{\endproof}
\begin{document}
\begin{myproof}
\blindtext
\end{myproof}
\begin{myproof}[Proof sketch]
\blindtext
\end{myproof}
\end{document}
```

[image: proof with line break]

Comment: Didn't you want to show in the first example, that you still can use the original `\begin{proof}` environment? Just saying:)

Answer (score 5):

Use `\ \\` after `\begin{proof}` like this: `\begin{proof}\ \\`.

This solution works fine for me with package `amsthm`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 

\begin{document} 

    \begin{proof}\ \\ 
        \blindtext 
    \end{proof} 

    \begin{proof}[Proof sketch]\ \\ 
        \blindtext 
    \end{proof} 

\end{document}
```

You will get something like:

[image]

Also, in case you want the new paragraph to be indented, you can start it with the command `\indent`. The code is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 

\begin{document} 

    \begin{proof}\ \\ 
        \indent\blindtext 
    \end{proof} 

    \begin{proof}[Proof sketch]\ \\ 
        \indent\blindtext 
    \end{proof} 

\end{document}
```

In this case, you will get something like:

[image]

PS. 
I borrowed the code from Stefan Kottwitz'answer.

Comment: This is simple and memorable, but you have to use \indent to indent.