# Automatically start a new line at the beginning of a proof environment?

Tags: amsmath, itemize

I use `amsmath` to provide the `proof` environment. However, if a `itemize` (or `tikzpicture`) environment immediately follows the `proof` environment, `xelatex` will produce a messy result:

```
\begin{proof}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}
```

Will produce something like this:

> *Proof*. * 1
>
> - 2

So I have to manually add a `\mbox` after the `proof` env. Is it possible to make `proof` automatically add a newline in these situations?

Comment: In my opinion it's better not to format a proof as an itemized or enumerated list. Just add at the beginning of the paragraph a marker (for instance the number of the substatement, or a symbol such as `($\Rightarrow$)`). Having a long (or even short) proof with a shifted margin makes for bad pages.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36851/skipping-line-after-proof-in-proof-environment and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85059/proof-environment-line-break-after-the-proof (so that this helps someone searching!)

Comment: These two questions asked for a newline without any condition. I want to have a 'smart' `proof`: only add a new line when the first 'thing' inside the `proof` is `itemize`, `enumerate`, `description`, `tikzpicture`, or something like these environments. Seems I did not make it clear in the first place. Sorry about that.

Comment: @egreg That is a good advice. But sometimes I need to start proof with a `tikzpicture`, and without `\mbox{}`, the `tikzpicture` will float at the top of the `proof` environment:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the proof environment and add a `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\mbox{}\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this code seems *always* add a `\mbox{}`. Is it possible to add `\mbox{}` only when it is needed (such as `itemize` immediately after `proof`?

Comment: @capsensitive: Indeeed. But in a normal case (without a `par` or empty line) it should work.

Comment: I see. That really is the perfect solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a good suggestion to manually redefine an enviornment which is often the result of complicated package work...