# Enumerate alignment in remark

Tags: lists, enumerate, amsart

I'm using amsart. When I create an enumeration inside a remark environment, the numbering is not aligned properly:

```
Remark. (1)
(2)
(3)
(4)
```

How do I shift the (1) nextline?

Remark.

(1)

(2)

(3)

(4)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\begin{document}
\begin{remark}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{remark}\mbox{}\begin{enumerate}...`

Comment: duplicate: [Is it possible to skip the first line in a theorem environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8110/579).  (the accepted answer is what is recommended for `amsthm` and ams document classes.)