# Creating line break for tabular table inside a theorem environment

Tags: tables, theorems

I have a table inside theorem environment and I would like to have a line break before the table is being drawn. Currently it will start drawing the table on the same line that the theorem is listed and it looks rather ugly. Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

I have an example in the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example} 

\begin{document}
  \begin{exmp}
     \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        $ row1 & row1 & row1 $\\
        $ row2 & row2 & row2 $\\
        $ row3 & row3 & row3 $\\ 
     \end{tabular}
  \end{exmp}
\end{document}
```

The solution is to add \leavevmode after \begin{exmp} and also leave a blank line before the tabular environment.

Comment: insert the command `\leavevmode` before the table.  (i'm sure this has been asked/answered before; i'll look for a dup.)

Comment: I was looking for something similar about this but wasn't able to find. Thank you for the suggestion though. I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: this question asks about starting a theorem environment with a list, not a tabular, but the principle is the same: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8110/579 and this one is also similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319717  (can't find an exact duplicate.  maybe it's time to create a "generic" question on this topic.)

Comment: off-topic: (i) `chapter` doesn't exist in `article` document class; (ii) use of `$` signs in table is wrong/fragile (what you like to achieve with them?); (iii) `\end{tabular}` is missing; (iv) your problem can be solved with adding `~` after `begin{exmp}` and insert blank line before table.

Comment: in addition to the `\leavevmode, leave a blank line after \begin{exmp}

Comment: @barbarabeeton This works. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: please don't edit the solution in to the question it makes the archived question very confusing. You could ask @barbarabeeton to make her comment in to an answer or you could post an answer yourself, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the header of a theorem object in `amsthm` always ends in horizontal mode.
the 'tabular' environment begins in horizontal mode, so if a table is to start
on a new line, it's necessary to enter vertical mode.  hence a blank line
will be needed.

but that's not enough, since the theorem definitions in `amsthm` ignore blank
lines in order for the text of a theorem to continue on the same line as the
header.  (this is an ams style specification.)  so in order for a blank line
to take effect, it's necessary to put something else on the "first line".

the recommended way to short-circuit the "something on the line" requirement
is to insert `\leavevmode`.  although this seems counterintuitive, it provides
a horizontal mode element that will allow the blank line to have the desired
effect of starting a new paragraph. the relevant part of the example should
look like this:

```
...
  \begin{exmp}
     \leavevmode

     \begin{tabular}{ccc}
...
```

another method is to add the string `$ $`.  however, this has the disadvantage
that it inserts something that takes physical space in the output, and in the
edge case where a header with optional added text exactly reaches the
right-hand margin, it can result in the addition of a physical blank line in
the output.

irrelevant to the question, the example provided has two flaws -- `article`
does not define `\chapter`, and the `$` signs in the `tabular` are out of
synch and result in errors when trying to process the file.