# Enumerate align problem inside theorem

Tags: environments, enumerate, amsthm

I am trying to add a separation between the beginning of a theorem environment and an enumeration.
I want this:

```
Theorem
 (1)
 (2)
 (3)
```

And not this:

```
Theorem (1)
 (2)
 (3)
```

I know a solution is using `\leavevmode`, but what I want to do is to automatically include this command inside my theorem environment, so I tried this:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{demo}{Demostración:}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{demo}{\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{demo}{\leavevmode}
\AfterEndEnvironment{demo}{\end{adjustwidth}}
```

But this is doing nothing. I mean, it doesn't give me an error, it just does nothing (but if I include `\leavevmode` after the `\begin{demo}` it works. I think I'm loading all the necessary packages.

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: this question should be relevant: [`theorem` environment : interaction with `enumerate`/`itemize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319717)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a new environment, built around a standard theorem.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{ltheorem}{\begin{theorem}\leavevmode}{\end{theorem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ltheorem}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
  \end{enumerate}
\end{ltheorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @PabloD. Since Andrew's answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).