# indent problems \newtheorem-environment

Tags: spacing

```
\begin{example}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{itemize}
\end{example}
```

where example defines a \newtheorem environment.
I want to avoid that my First item appears in the same line where example stays.

Comment: Add `\mbox{}` after `\begin{example}`.

Comment: thanks, it works!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Potential duplicate: [`theorem` environment : interaction with `enumerate`/`itemize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319717)