# Cross reference not working properly

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsart

```
 \documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{amsart}
 \usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsaddr, amssymb, graphicx, dsfont,}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=Blue,
citecolor=Brown]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}

\raggedbottom

 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
 \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
 \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
 \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
 \newtheorem{example}{Example}
 \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
 \newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
body={6.5in, 9.0in},
left=1.25in,
right=1.25in,
top=1.25in,
bottom=1.25in
}

%\usepackage{footmisc}
%\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm} %footnote spacing

 \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ima}{Im}
\newcommand{\namedthm}[2]{\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{thm#1}{Theorem #1}\begin{thm#1}#2\end{thm#1}}

\usepackage{float}

\title[Test]{Test}\thanks{Test}

\author[A]{A}\address{University of LaTeX}

 \author[B]{B}\address{University of LaTeX} 

\date{\today}

 \begin{document}


 \maketitle 


 \begin{abstract}
 Test

\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{alpha}


\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Introduction}

Test

\section{General Results}\label{General}\bigskip

 \begin{theorem}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item[(i)] a. 
  \item[(ii)] b.
  \item[(iii)] c.
 \item[(iv)] d.
\item[(v)] e. 
\end{itemize}
\label{main}
 \end{theorem}\bigskip

Theorem \ref{main}.\bigskip

\end{document}
```

In the pdf generated, when one clicks the "1" in "Theorem 1", it jumps to the title page rather than where the Theorem 1 is. How shall I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: don't confuse hyperref by creating the page 1 twice, e.g. set the numbering style of the title page to alpha.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But the title page is not numbered now.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you see the page number or not. If it is has the same number as the following page hyperref don't like it. Use \pagenumbering{alpha} before the title page and \pagenumbering{arabic} later.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I made the change accordingly (the code is now updated) but the problem remains. Maybe I misunderstood what you mean by "before" and "later".

Comment: hm, at first amsart doesn't like the \pagenumbering{alpha}. Do you really want to reset the numbering after the title? The class doesn't really support this. Beside this you shouldn't start the theorem with an itemize (or other lists), that swallows the destination. Add some normal text there.

Comment: I'm not sure what packages are supposed to be loaded *after* `hyperref`, but I'm quite sure that `hyperref` should be closer to `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use `hyperref` at the last package, and you kept both `\label` and `\ref` in a same page, I've slightly modified your `MWE`

```
\documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{amsart}
 \usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsaddr, amssymb, graphicx, dsfont,}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}

\raggedbottom

 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
 \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
 \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
 \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
 \newtheorem{example}{Example}
 \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
 \newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
body={6.5in, 9.0in},
left=1.25in,
right=1.25in,
top=1.25in,
bottom=1.25in
}

 \usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=Blue,
citecolor=Brown]{hyperref}

 \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ima}{Im}
\newcommand{\namedthm}[2]{\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{thm#1}{Theorem #1}\begin{thm#1}#2\end{thm#1}}

\usepackage{float}

\title[Test]{Test}\thanks{Test}

\author[A]{A}\address{University of LaTeX}

 \author[B]{B}\address{University of LaTeX} 

\date{\today}

 \begin{document}


 \maketitle 


 \begin{abstract}
 Test

\end{abstract}

\clearpage


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Introduction}

Test

\section{General Results}\label{General}\bigskip

 \begin{theorem}\label{main}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item[(i)] a. 
  \item[(ii)] b.
  \item[(iii)] c.
 \item[(iv)] d.
\item[(v)] e. 
\end{itemize}
 \end{theorem}\bigskip

Theorem \ref{main}.\bigskip

\clearpage

Test for hyperlink \ref{main}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your code but the problem remains.

Comment: Hope the problem might be in your `TeX` release, please use the updated setup...

Comment: I am using Overleaf. And the problem is caused by \itemize in the theorem.

Comment: @Ypbor Hope your issue got solved...

Comment: @Ypbor -- After `\begin{theorem}\label{main}` insert `\leavevmode`.  See  [`theorem` environment : interaction with `enumerate`/`itemize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319717)