# hyperref makes `\ref{x}` point to last page for`\label{x}` when that is followed by `\begin{enumerate}` (with enumerate package)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumerate

The following document shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\begin{document}
  \chapter{first chapter}
  The reference to theorem \ref{thm:structureunoriented1} is correctly displayed (2.1 in this case) but points to the last page of the document with {\ttfamily warning  (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name 'thm.2.1'} during compilation.
  \newpage
  \chapter{second chapter}
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:structureunoriented1}
%%    \phantom{x}  % Uncommenting this line prevents the problem
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
        \item This is the part 1 of the theorem I want to refer to.
        \item This is the part 2 of the theorem I want to refer to.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{thm}
  \newpage
  \chapter{third chapter}
  This is where I land when klicking on the reference.
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure who the culprit is but one of the packages `hyperref` and `enumerate` is, right? Is there a way to avoid that problem? After all `\phantom` is not very elegant. Putting the label after `\end{enumerate}` works but then I land on the bottom of the theorem.

Comment: with a current hyperref it works fine, I corrected that a few months ago.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, thanks! I thought I had the most recent version (I'm using Opensuse tumbleweed which as a rolling distribution I thought was up to date.)

Comment: the current hyperref version is 2023-06-25 v7.01a.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, mine is 2023.201.7.00vsvn65758. So I probably can safely install the newer version under ~/texmf right? (I don't want to mess with the system packages.)

Comment: texmf might be the system packages, depending on your installation.  I think you'd want to look for texmf-local.

Comment: `amsthm` defines `theorem` to be run-in.  It expects something (i.e. text) to follow before a "vertical" environment like `enumerate`.  See the questions about starting a theorem with a list; this one might suffice: [`theorem` environment : interaction with `enumerate`/`itemize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319717)