# Newline after theorem doesn't work if it starts with \begin{enumerate}

Tags: line-breaking, theorems, newtheorem

[This method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37805/27733) to have a newline after the exercise heading usually works:

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*),align=left,leftmargin=*}

\begin{exercise}
Hello
\end{exercise}
```

and gives:

> Exercise 1
>   Hello

But when the exercise begins with an enumeration, it fails:

```
\begin{exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

with:

> Exercise 1 1) Hello

**Question: how to have the newline after the exercise heading, even if starts with an `enumerate`?**

Note:

- the two first answers from [Is it possible to skip the first line in a theorem environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/is-it-possible-to-skip-the-first-line-in-a-theorem-environment) *nearly work*, but adding either `\leavemode` or `mbox{}` after the `\begin{exercise}` doesn't produce

  > Exercise 1
  >   1) Hello

  but

  > Exercise 1
  >   < empty line >
  >   Hello

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8110/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17449/35864 help?

Comment: Thank you @moewe. I edited the question to show why the first answers from the first link didn't work, probably specific to `\newtheoremstyle{break}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}` mode.

Comment: Try `\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}`

Comment: Do you think @moewe we could define this once for all in this definition `\newtheoremstyle{break}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline \leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}}{}` and avoid to have to think about it when we start an exercise with or without enumeration? (If so, you could post it as an answer).

Comment: I'm no sure about the possible downsides in certain edge cases, so I'd rather not recommend it. Plus it seems excessive in the 'usual case'.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8146/27733), this is the solution in this precise case:

```
\begin{exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[]
\item First item
```

All the other answers don't really work in this specific case because they create new paragraphs, letting empty lines between the Exercise heading and the enumeration.